# Extending a volume on RHEL5 through Hyper-v

Tags: extend, volume, hyper-v, rhel5

I installed a RHEL version 5 on a hyper-v virtual machine with initially 50 gigs.  I expanded the hard drive to 100gigs but now I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to extend that volume size to 100gigs from 50gigs.  Is there a correct way using the GUI included in Red hat enterprise linux 5 or from the terminal?

Every link i search is telling me to use this 3rd party app to extend my volume.  I just want to either do it through the GUI or the terminal.

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                        45G  6.0G   37G  15% /
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
tmpfs                 941M     0  941M   0% /dev/shm
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14        6527    52323705   8e  Linux LVM
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found my answer.   I found this link

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006371

Good guide on extending the size of RHEL after expanding the virtual disc from Hyper-V